# Fastest way to load an logo (image) ans save it in a xlsx in r

Tags: r

How can I load a logo (PNG) into r to save that with my report generated in r.

I have tried below:

```
Logo<- imager::load.image("~/Logo/Logo.JPG")
plot(Logo)
```

The problem is that imager inserts x and y coordination axis to the image, which I don't want that.

Regards,=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TLDR

You can suppress the axes by setting `axes=FALSE`. Try

```
plot(Logo, axes=FALSE)
```

Let me add how I found this answer so that anybody could do it.

`plot` will do different things depending on what type of object you try to plot.
What is `Logo`?

```
str(Logo)
## OR
class(Logo)
```

and you will see that it is an object of type cimg. Therefore,  plot will check to see if there is a function called `plot.cimg` (which there is). So you can just look at the help page - not for `plot` but for `plot.cimg`.

```
help(plot.cimg)
```

It lists the arguments for this function including the `axes` argument.